# New Joomla install but can't install extensions. Get 500 Internal Server error

Tags: extensions, installation, joomla-3.9

Tried installing extensions 'from Web' and installing 'from Folder'. The files were added to the /tmp folder and extracted, but did not get installed. Screen jumps from installing to 500 error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

- Fresh/new installed Joomla version 3.9.16
- PHP 7.3.15
- Web Server    Microsoft-IIS/8.5

Cleared cache. Switched between Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Same issue.

Logged in as SuperUser with full access permissions.

Couldn't find any error logs.

Ran a check and repair on sql db and 6 errors found, but does not self-repair when applied:

> - Warning bak_pdfinder_tokens The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> - Warning bak_pdfinder_tokens_aggregate   The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> - Warning bak_pd_finder_tokens    The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> - Warning bak_pd_finder_tokens_aggregate  The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> - Warning pdfinder_tokens The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
> - Warning pdfinder_tokens_aggregate   The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify your xml file
2. Try unnistalling and installing your extension
3. Drop the table manually

Also verify your PhpMyAdmin make sure it's Mysql and the engine is InnoDB.

Comment: 1. xml tested fine

Comment: 1) xml tested fine, 2) I can't see the component so uninstalling is not an option. I tried installing a different extension but same problem.3) Dropped 4) All tables show type=InnoDB except dropped tables =MEMORY

Answer (score 1):

Well, i recommend you that you change your server from Microsoft Web Server to a more approriate server for php, such as WampServer.

WampServer has some configurations you must pay attention to. If you are ever going to install it, make sure to select mysql on the installation process (since it's more compatible with Joomla) and set mysql as your default DBMS after you have installed it. Don't forget to disable/uninstall the IIS.

PS: Do a new installation of Joomla if possible. If you have a custom template, backup your template and, eventually, your database.

[Download WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Joomla is installed on a hosted server so I don't have any options for a WAMP setup. Database is mysql. I have done a new installation of Joomla but same problem. .. I guess I could set up a wampserver and joomla on my local computer, then try installing extensions and revise the website files but that seems like a lot of extra work and how can I be sure the extensions won't crash once I upload the site to the hosted server.

Comment: Yes, you can try doing that. If that works, you can contact your hosting provider asking to change from Windows to Linux ( some hosting providers change the host type).  Because actually windows hosting is suitable for ASP and related.

Answer (score 1):

Check and verify the Global Config settings for Log Folder Path and Temp Folder Path, and make sure they are correct, they are within your domain's root folder, and their permissions are good (should by writable, 0755).

These paths can sometimes go adrift, often for domains that have been restored from backups. If they are wrong, then either the site's logging or installers will break.

Comment: Please take our [tour] to earn your first badge.